# Mask Image with CGPath

Tags: ios7, sprite-kit

If I use this code, without fill the path , I have the masked image with the border only (correctly).

But I want the Shape filled, and if I add

```
[Maschera setFillColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

for fill the Shape I have a rectangle instead of the polygon shape filled

WHY?!?

the `CGPathRef` is correctly call for draw other figure and work correctly

(thanks and sorry for my English)

```
background =  [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Pista1.jpg"];
background.xScale = 0.5;
background.yScale = 0.5;
[background setAnchorPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
SKCropNode *cropNode = [[SKCropNode alloc] init];
SKShapeNode *Maschera = [SKShapeNode node];
Maschera.antialiased = YES;
Maschera.path = pathToDraw;

//===>>>> Fill the Shape , but result is rectangle =>>>  [Maschera setFillColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

cropNode.maskNode =Maschera;//

[cropNode addChild:background];

[self addChild:cropNode];
```

Comment: Have you tested just adding the circle filled by itself to see if it looks right?